# How to add JS files in cargo collective

Tags: javascript

Hi we're students studying visual design, and we barely know how to code
We are trying to add some interactions on our web made through cargo collective.
And we want to find a way to add some java script files on our web.
-such as p5.play.js libraries(http://molleindustria.github.io/p5.play/)-

We made it work on HTML but it failed when we tried to upload it on cargo collective.
This is what we did on cargo collective:
uploaded the js file by clicking the File icon, copied it's link, and added it on Custom HTML.
Does anybody know a way to solve this?

Comment: Can you post the html and js

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>practice</title>
    <script src="p5.js"></script>
<script src="drawing.js"></script>
<script src="p5.play.js"></script>
    <style>
h1{font-size: 45px;
text-align: center;
font-family: "Helvetica";
  }
    </style>

  <h1>Hi!</h1>
  <h1>기업디를 위한 웹 연습 페이지</h1>

  </head>

  <body>



  </body>
</html>

this is the HTML

Comment: You can add `defer` to the script tags since you placed them in the head, so they only execute when the DOM has been loaded

Comment: And ensure that p5.js and p5.play.js is also on the folder you are running from

Comment: OMG thank you so much we'll try this!!!